# Will you please tell me how to set custom phpmd ruleset file in netbeans 8.1?

Tags: netbeans-8, phpmd

I'm installing phpmd into netbeans and it gives me error also but what if I want to set my custom ruleset file in netbeans 8.1?

Comment: I got the answer.....                                                                                                                  After creating custom standard file using [link][https://phpmd.org/documentation/creating-a-ruleset.html]     place this file to [main][usr/share/data/PHPMD/resources/rulesets]                                                                      I make file custom standard rules file name with [bold]customPHPMD.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.....
After creating custom standard file using [link](https://phpmd.org/documentation/creating-a-ruleset.htm)
place this file to [main][usr/share/data/PHPMD/resources/rulesets]
I make file custom standard rules file name with [bold][customPHPMD.xml]

for that I Write some command on terminal

```
cd usr/share/data/PHPMD/resources/rulesets
sudo nano customPHPMD.xml
sudo chmod 777 cusomtPHPMD.xml
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="My first PHPMD rule set"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0
                     http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="
                     http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">
    <description>
        My custom rule set that checks my code...
    </description>

    <!-- Import the entire unused code rule set -->
    <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml/CyclomaticComplexity" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml/NPathComplexity" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml/ExcessiveMethodLength" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml/ExcessiveClassLength" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml/ExcessiveParameterList" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml/TooManyFields" />  
    <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml/TooManyMethods" /> 
    <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml/ExcessiveClassComplexity" />   
    <rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/CamelCaseClassName" />
    <rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/CamelCasePropertyName" /> 
    <rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/CamelCaseMethodName" />           
    <rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/CamelCaseParameterName" />    
    <rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/ExitExpression" />    
    <rule ref="rulesets/design.xml/ExitExpression" />   
</ruleset>
```

after This Rightclick on project->properties->phpcsmd

[image: and add customPHPMD rule inside rule tab of phpmd]